# JavaScript: get all form elements under a fieldset

Tags: javascript

How can I get all the elements of a form, specifically under a fieldset, by using the following syntax:

```
document.forms[formName]
```

The above contains ALL the elements of the form, but what if I want to get only the elements under FIELDSET1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
console.log(document.forms['formName'].querySelectorAll('#FIELDSET1 *'))
```

```html
<form name="formName">
<fieldset id="FIELDSET1">
<input>
<select></select>
<input>
<select></select>
</fieldset>

<select></select>
<input>
</form>
```